# Handle SizeChanged Event on Application Window C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, windows-runtime

i try handle SizeChanged Event on change application Window dimensions.

But when i try this code:

```
Window::Current().CoreWindow().SizeChanged(TypedEventHandler<Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow, Windows::UI::Core::WindowSizeChangedEventArgs>([=](Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow const sender, Windows::UI::Core::WindowSizeChangedEventArgs const&) {
    WindowResize(Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Current().Bounds().Width);
}));
```

OR

```
Window::Current().CoreWindow().SizeChanged([=](Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow const sender, Windows::UI::Core::WindowSizeChangedEventArgs const&) {
    WindowResize(Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Current().Bounds().Width);
});
```

i got error:
`error C3779: 'winrt::impl::consume_Windows_UI_Core_ICoreWindow<winrt::Windows::UI::Core::ICoreWindow>::SizeChanged': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined`

Comment: You forgot to `#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h>`. C++/WinRT requires you to include the headers for any namespace you consume.

Comment: Thank you! Good learn for future :)